# Gauge for showing reading android

Tags: android

According to my need i want to create gauge like this with multiple colors.how can i achieve this in android

[image]

Comment: what did you tried so far? any efforts from your side

Comment: yes i tried many times  i used this lib https://github.com/anastr/SpeedView  and create the same view but this lib getting me to set only 3 colors in view but according to my need i want to set many colors with different ranges

Comment: check this https://github.com/ntoskrnl/SpeedometerView

Comment: i think background will not show the same

Comment: i have to manage customly